# Adding hashes in Content-Security-Policy: style-src

Tags: html, content-security-policy, google-translate

I have just added Google Translate's JavaScript tool to my project. I've gone through and added hashes to my script-src and it is working. The issue is that I am still getting errors in the console about styles that cannot be loaded, even after I've added the hash to style-src (Chrome)

Sample Error Message:

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'sha256-+cU/VT0vv47hxLJZovgG53kGPWPopxhXhYgUD6IR5Ro=' 'sha256-2Ohx/ATsoWMOlFyvs2k+OujvqXKOHaLKZnHMV8PRbIc=' 'sha256-qQUBUjasnJdhrNlgzajDJnnOf9HGERy1tkajP7dru0c=' 'sha256-B6LEPigs3viM+y/BwYQU665laXgIDFgp+sr+sdoaJqQ=' translate.googleapis.com 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-qQUBUjasnJdhrNlgzajDJnnOf9HGERy1tkajP7dru0c='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.`

You can see that I have the hash already in my CSP.

Also, adding hashes in exactly this way took care of my inline-script error messages.

Sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 
translate.google.com translate.googleapis.com localhost www.gstatic.com www.google.com 
'sha256-qQUBUjasnJdhrNlgzajDJnnOf9HGERy1tkajP7dru0c=' 
'sha256-+cU/VT0vv47hxLJZovgG53kGPWPopxhXhYgUD6IR5Ro=' ws: wss:; object-src 'none'; 

script-src 'sha256-NNiElek2Ktxo4OLn2zGTHHeUR6b91/P618EXWJXzl3s=' 
'sha256-97l24HYIWEdSIQ8PoMHzpxiGCZuyBDXtN19RPKFsOgk=' 

'sha256-w65k1oeqcYS7ejRz7pWG6X3uKVFzmotHeiJkjIE7LQY=' 
'sha256-qQUBUjasnJdhrNlgzajDJnnOf9HGERy1tkajP7dru0c=' 'self' 
translate.google.com translate.googleapis.com translate-pa.googleapis.com; 

style-src 
'sha256-+cU/VT0vv47hxLJZovgG53kGPWPopxhXhYgUD6IR5Ro=' 
'sha256-2Ohx/ATsoWMOlFyvs2k+OujvqXKOHaLKZnHMV8PRbIc=' 
'sha256-qQUBUjasnJdhrNlgzajDJnnOf9HGERy1tkajP7dru0c=' 
'sha256-B6LEPigs3viM+y/BwYQU665laXgIDFgp+sr+sdoaJqQ=' translate.googleapis.com 'self'; "/>

<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>
<Table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change to get rid of these inline style error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that while adding hashes to the CSP works for scripts (at least with google translate), it does not work for styles. But since google translate is working perfectly without these styles, the errors in the console are irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, but It is not the solution